# Is it better to store a reference to a file in a DB table column or just check the file exists

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm building a .Net/Sql Server site that has a User profile page that can show a profile photo of the person if it exists.  I'm storing the photos on a local folder on the server.  Each user has their own sub folder which is named using their DB generated User ID.  and the photo file is always called profile.jpg
In the DB I have a User table to store the profile data and I was thinking of adding a column called profile_photo_exists to indicate if a profile photo exists.

My question is, is this profile_photo_exists column redundant when I could just get some server-side code to check the user's folder to see if a photo file is there or not.   I was thinking that it would be better to have a DB column for this as checking the file system each time might not be that performant. My issue with this though is that it seems like a duplication of data, and I'm afraid of it going out of synch. E.g  File is missing from the folder but the DB says there is one.

Are there any other good reasons to keep the column?

Comment: Would it be better if the image be stored in the DB and tied via an ID to the user account?

Comment: I'm currently building an AJAX site and my plan is store everything in a DB. I'm doing this by calling asp web service functions.

Comment: The problem with doing it like that is that it doesn't scale.  What if you want to me your images to a CDN? or some other external storage.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Azure databases come to mind though. I'm still learning so don't mind me. I love being corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The performance impact of using System.IO to check if a file exists is very small. Like you mentioned, the problem with storing the flag "profile_photo_exists" is having to keep this flag in sync with your database - seems like an unnecessary complication.

What I would probably do is save uploaded profile pictures using the user's user id. Ex. user-id.jpg "65d476eb-f52c-4faf-bec2-93073daad6ec.jpg".  That'll help to normalize the names of the profile pics.

Then have some simple logic that checks for a custom profile picture and if it doesn't exist load the "default.jpg".

I'd also think about whether you need to store a default.jpg in each user folder - seems redundant?  Why not just save one default.jpg in case you can't find a custom profile pic for a user?  Having one default.jpg makes it easier if you ever want to change the default profile image and takes up less space on your servers.

Just my $.02.  I hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly how I build it. Using the userid as the filename removes the unnecessary db call in order to get the image location.